# How to Obtain AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret for Twitter?

Tags: c#, twitter

HI I register application with Twitter. as a result I got all necessary information (consumer key, consumer secret, api key etc) except AccessToken and AccessTokenSecret.

How to get them?

Answer (score 2):

go to the link below:
https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new

Fill up the form then submit.

At the right navigation you will find the nav named
'My Access Token'  click it

now you will get your Access Token and AccessTokenSecret

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a to use a single token...

To retrieve your own access token, go to the detail page of one of your applications and select the My Token link from the sidebar.

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_single_token

Otherwise, you will need to attain the AccessTokens you need programmatically using OAuth.

http://dev.twitter.com/auth